# About vector-push_back and returning pointer

Tags: c++

I have a question that is related to `School::addStudent(...)`

This is from `class School` coding.

```
    class School {

        string schoolName ;
        vector<Student> students;
    public:
        School(const string& _schoolName) : schoolName(_schoolName) {}
        Student* addStudent(const string& name, MajorType majorType) {
        students.push_back(Student(name, 0, majorType));
        return &students[students.size()-1];
        }
    Student* addStudent(const string& name, const float gpa) {
        students.push_back(Student(name, gpa, UD));
        return &students[students.size()-1];
        }
    ...
    }
```

This is from `class Student` coding

```
    class Student {
        string name;
        float gpa;
        Major major;
    public:
        Student() : name("null"), major(UD) {
            this->gpa=0;
        }
        Student(const string& _name, const float _gpa, const Major _major) 
                : name(_name), major(_major) {
                gpa = _gpa;
            }
        void set(const string& _name, MajorType _majorType) {
            name = _name;
            this->gpa=0;
            major.setMajor(_majorType);
        }
        void set(const string& _name, const float gpa) {
            name = _name;
            this->gpa = gpa;
            major.setMajor(UD);
        }
        void setName(const string& _name) {
            name = _name;
        }
        void setGPA(const float gpa) {
            this->gpa = gpa;
        }
        void setMajor(const MajorType majorType) {
            major.setMajor(majorType);
        }
    } ;
```

This is class Major.

```
    class Major { 
        MajorType majorType ;
    public:
        Major(const MajorType _majorType) : majorType(_majorType) {}
    
        MajorType getmajorType() const {
            return majorType;
        }
        void setMajor(const MajorType _majorType) {
            majorType=_majorType;
        }
    };
```

This is a simple enumeration. Skip if you want to.

```
    enum MajorType {CE, EE, ME, UD};
```

---

Here is the problem.
When I code `Student* addStudent` this way, it works just fine.

But when I code `Student* addStudent`

```
        Student* addStudent(const string& name, MajorType majorType) {
            Student* tmp = new Student();
            tmp->set(name, majorType);
            students.push_back(*tmp);
            return tmp;
        }
        Student* addStudent(const string& name, const float gpa) {
            Student* tmp = new Student();
            tmp->set(name, gpa);
            students.push_back(*tmp);
            return tmp;
        }
```

this way it does not work.
it does compile, but when it hits kim->setGPA in the main code, the following number doesn't go in to the vectorstudents. I think this is related to memory address and copy by value but I don't know why my code is going haywire.

for those who want to know the result of the latter code

> School Name: PNU, Count: 4
> Name: Kim GPA : 0 Major: Electrical Eng.
> Name: Hong GPA : 0 Major: Computer Eng.
> Name: Lee GPA : 4 Major: Undecided.
> Name: Joo GPA : 1.5 Major: Undecided.

the main code has bits that has inputs about Kim and Hong's GPA and Lee and Joo's Major but the code just doesn't work

Thank you for reading this long problem of mine and I would be very grateful if you could solve this problem since I have been thinking since yesterday

Comment: You were mistaken into thinking that "this way" works "just fine". Any `push_back` into a vector can reallocate the vector, invalidating all existing pointers to the vector. Which happened to be returned from your previous calls to `addStudent`(). Hillarity ensues. Oh, and the "doesn't" work fine version is also broken, but in a completely different way. None of the shown alternatives of `addStudent` work correctly, for different reasons.

Comment: You allocate a new student. You set up the new student. Then you copy the student and put the copy in the vector. Then you return a pointer to the original student. Of course if you change the original student, it does not change the copy, because the copy is a completely different student.

Comment: what is your specific question? I have the impression that you are mixing too many things in what you wrote. Good that you made some research and tried different things, but it makes the question hard to follow. Please try to reduce your code to one [mcve].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are you sure that _any `push_back` can reallocate_? I think that `push_back` can reallocate only if capacity equals size. (Such that, if you `reserve`, `push_back` _must not_ reallocate until the capacity is full.)

Comment: @DanielLangr `addStudent` isn't documented to have a precondition on `students`' capacity, so yes, a call to `addStudent` *might* reallocate

Comment: Yes, @DanielLangr, a vector reallocates only when capacity is equal to size. But unless this gets explicitly checked for, it logically means that any push_back can reallocate. Since you do not know if when any particular push_back happens whether reallocation will or will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports Cpp11, replace

```
 vector<Student> students;
```

with

```
 vector<std::shared_ptr<Student>> students;
```

and work with shared pointers instead.

see [shared pointer documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

This should also relieve the memory leak in your current code.

```
Student* addStudent(const string& name, const float gpa) {
    Student* tmp = new Student();
    tmp->set(name, gpa);
    students.push_back(*tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```